# IQueryable Query Performance Tuning

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I would like some suggestions for how to make this simple LINQ code to be as fast and efficient as possible

> tbl_WatchList contains 51996 rows
>
> The below test takes 2 secs to run according to VS2012 test explorer

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRemoveWatch()
    {
        using (var DB = new A4C_2012_devEntities())
        {
            var results = DB.tbl_WatchList.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(1);
            int WatchID = results.AsEnumerable().First().ID;
            Assert.IsTrue(WatchList.RemoveWatch(WatchID));
        }
    }
```

Comment: what so wrong with this question, why the downvotes?

Comment: Try removing AsEnumerable. And if you really want performnce, skip EF and linq all together..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to sort whole collection.

```
int WatchID = DB.tbl_WatchList.Max(wl => wl.ID);
```

Should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize, do the following:

- Use a profiling tool (such as SQL profiler) to see what SQL queries are sent to the database and to see what the real performance is of those queries.
- Select the slow performing queries and analyse there query plan manually or use an Index Tuning Advisor to see what indexes you are missing.
- Add the missing indexes.